# Media3 ExoPlayer Update Notification Title during playback

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, android-media3, mediasession

I'm using **Media3 [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/media/implement/playback-app)@1.2.0** with a `PlaybackService` that extends [MediaSessionService](https://developer.android.com/media/media3/session/background-playback)

using `setMediaNotificationProvider` to create a `Notification` for API below 33.

```java
public class PlaybackService extends MediaSessionService {

    public void onCreate() {

        // Initialize ExoPlayer
        ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this, ...).build();

        setMediaNotificationProvider(new MediaNotification.Provider() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MediaNotification createNotification(@NonNull MediaSession mediaSession, @NonNull ImmutableList<CommandButton> customLayout, @NonNull MediaNotification.ActionFactory actionFactory, @NonNull Callback onNotificationChangedCallback) {

                createMediaNotification(mediaSession);

                return new MediaNotification(PLAYBACK_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
            }

            // ...
        });

        // ...

    });

    public void createMediaNotification(MediaSession mediaSession) {

        MediaMetadata metadata = mediaSession.getPlayer().getMediaMetadata();

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(PlaybackService.this, PLAYBACK_CHANNEL_ID)
            // ...
            .setContentTitle(metadata.title)
            .setContentText(metadata.description)
            .setStyle(new MediaStyleNotificationHelper.MediaStyle(mediaSession));

    }

}
```

in `MainActivity` i set the `MediaMetaData` (title/description)

```java
List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();

MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
    .setMediaId(ITEM_ID)
    .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder()
            .setTitle(ITEM_TITLE)
            .setDescription(ITEM_DESCRIPTION)
            // ..
    .setUri(ITEM_URI)
.build();

mediaItems.add(mediaItem);

player.setMediaItems(mediaItems);

player.prepare();
player.play();
```

**TLDR:** i need to update title/description of the media playback notification (during playback), after it's already set before using `.setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder().setTitle(..))` and `.setContentTitle(metadata.title)`

Now, what i'm trying to achieve, lets say at some point `(during playback)` i need to **update the title/description** (or MediaMetaData title/description) of the Notification for the current playing media item, wether it is the `Media3 Session Notification` or `Legacy Notification` below API Level 33

```java
// a method in MainActivity
private void onPlayerProgressChanged(long current_playback_time) {

    if(current_playback_time >= something) {
        
        // Here need to update the notification title/description
        // Like .setDescription("Something else")
    }

}
```

Here's how it's currently working:

[image]

I can't seem to find any documentation or workaround to achieve this approach, don't know either it's possible or not.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to update the **MediaMetaData** `title` during playback by calling `player.replaceMediaItem(..)` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/androidx/media/issues/951#issuecomment-1880922883)

```java
MediaItem oldItem = player.getCurrentMediaItem();

if(oldItem != null) {
    MediaItem newItem = oldItem
        .buildUpon()
        .setMediaMetadata(player.getMediaMetadata()
            .buildUpon()
            .setTitle("New Title")
            .build())
        .build();
    player.replaceMediaItem(player.getCurrentMediaItemIndex(), newItem);
}
```

> In this way, the player can emit an **EVENT_MEDIA_METADATA_CHANGED**
> event, and media3 session **MediaNotificationManager** or legacy
> **PlayerNotificationManager** can update the notification when receive the
> metadata changed event.